# Why passing local object to initialize another object is fine but passing reference of a local object to initialize another object is not

Tags: c++, reference

I wrote the following code.

```
#include <iostream>
 using namespace std; 
 class Cat
{
 public:
  int itsage;
};
 
 Cat myFunction()
{
 Cat Frisky;
 Frisky.itsage=2;
 return Frisky;
}
 int main()
{
 Cat Mani=myFunction();
 cout << Mani.itsage;
 cout << endl;
 return 0;
}
```

**Output** `2`

Then I wrote the following code.

```
#include <iostream>
 using namespace std; 
 class Cat
{
 public:
  int itsage;
};
 
 Cat & myFunction()
{
 Cat Frisky;
 Frisky.itsage=2;
 return Frisky;
}
 int main()
{
 Cat Mani=myFunction();
 cout << Mani.itsage;
 cout << endl;
 return 0;
}
```

After compiling, I receive warning as `reference to local variable 'Frisky' returned` and didn't get any output.

I am confused why first code worked but second didn't. To be specific, I have following two questions:

**Question 1** Is this how first code worked?

Step 1: `Frisky` got created.

Step 2: statement `return Frisky` got executed, which returned `Frisky` and `Mani` got initialized in `main`.

Step 3: `myFunction` ended which immediately destroyed `Frisky`. But as `Mani` was already initialized, this didn't created any issue.

Step 4: As `Mani` was initialized with `Frisky`, `Mani.itsage` gave output as `2`.

Am I correct here? If not, please correct me.

**Question 2** Why I thought my second code should have run.

Step 1: `Frisky` got created.

Step 2: statement `return Frisky` got executed, which returned the `reference of Frisky`(someone who is exact copy of Frisky) and `Mani` got initialized in `main`(with that exact copy of Frisky).

Step 3: Step 3: `myFunction` ended which immediately destroyed `Frisky`. But as `Mani` was already initialized, this didn't created any issue.

This is what I thought. But clearly I have messed up somewhere.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a misconception in steps 2 and 3 in both descriptions.

The actual order is:

- `return Frisky` is executed which returns a copy of (code 1) or reference to (code 2) the local variable.
- The function ends and all local variables are destroyed. This does not affect the return value in code 1.
- `Mani` is initialized with a still-existing copy of (code 1) or a reference to a non-existing (code 2) `Cat` instance.

Comment: I am confused then why first one works? If I apply the steps you gave to first code, then why Mani didn't get initialized with non-existing Frisky?

Comment: Because the first code returns a copy of the local variable, not a reference to it. Modern compilers may optimize the copying away while keeping the semantics.